# Extension update server - targetplatform to support 4.2 and later

Tags: development, extension-update, versions, regex

I want my extension to support Joomla 4.2 and later, what should I write for the `targetplatform` in that case? Will `4.*` do the trick?

Writing something like `4.[2|3]` for the `targetplatform` is not a good option for me as it requires a manual effort every new minor Joomla version.

Comment: Perhaps something like `<targetplatform name="joomla" version="^(4\.([2-9]|10))\b"/>`?

Comment: Yes it did the trick :) https://regex101.com/r/Z9OGls/1, please post as answer.

Comment: A good explanation is here https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/31455/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess it kind of depends how far you want to pre-emptively include versions in your pattern:

- 4.2 only:    `^4\.2\b`
- 4.2 to 4.3:  `^4\.[23]\b`
- 4.2 to 4.4:  `^4\.[2-4]\b`
- 4.2 to 4.5:  `^4\.[2-5]\b`
- 4.2 to 4.6:  `^4\.[2-6]\b`
- 4.2 to 4.7:  `^4\.[2-7]\b`
- 4.2 to 4.8:  `^4\.[2-8]\b`
- 4.2 to 4.9:  `^4\.[2-9]\b`
- 4.2 to 4.10: `^4\.([2-9]|10)\b`
- 4.2 to 4.11: `^4\.([2-9]|1[01])\b`
- 4.2 or higher in 4: `^4\.([2-9]|[1-9]\d+)\b` ...yes, [this ridiculously matches version 4.347](https://regex101.com/r/5g1yKb/1) and beyond
- 4.2 through 5:    `^(5|4\.([2-9]|[1-9]\d+))\b`

The important thing to note is that these patterns are matching only the front portion of the version string.  If there are addition trailing characters, they are deemed unimportant. In other words, `4.6.3` will be matched by a pattern that allows `4.6`; the trailing `.3` is irrelevant to the logic.

The use of the word boundary (`\b`) could have been replaced with `(?!\d)` to ensure that the next character is not a digit -- but I prefer the brevity of `\b`.  In all of my patterns, the character before the `\b` is a digit (considered a "word" according to `\w`), then the "word boundary" character insists that if there is a next character, it must be a "non-word" (something that matches `\W`).

Please see [my earlier post](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/31455/12352) for the explanation of some of the subpatterns.

p.s. As a note on @Dmitrijs's spitballed pattern of `4.[2|3]`, it is important to note that `.` represents a wildcard to the regex engine and will be satisfied by any non-newline character.  Also, the square braced expression is called a "character class" -- it holds a list of all allowed characters.  A character class does not respect the pipe character to mean "or" -- it will be literally interpreted as a pipe symbol.  So as a worse case demonstration, `4.[2|3]` will happily match `4&|` ...which is not intended.